# How to return from catch in redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an action that call some api if `status` return 404, I want to return it from catch. And I call this action directly in react component but not recive it from action.

*action*

```
const someAction = (tagId, token) => dispatch => {
dispatch({
        type: TagAssignmentActionTypes.TagAssignmentChanged,
    })

    let status, assignee, response
    try {
        response = await DeviceApi.checkTagAssignment(tagId, token)

        assignee = response.result.assignee
        status = response.result.status
        return response.result
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, 'eeeeeeee')
        if (e && e.status === httpStatusCode.notFound)
            status = TagStatus.NotFound
        return status
    }

    dispatch({
        type: TagAssignmentActionTypes.TagAssignmentChanged,
        status,
        assignee,
        response,
    })
}
```

*function in react component*

```
 lookupComplete = (tagId = this.state.tagId) => this.setState({tagId}, async () => {

        let person, status
        let result = await this.props.someAction(parseInt(tagId, 16), this.props.accessToken)

        console.log(result.status, 'status')
        status = result.status

        person = this.props.persons[result.assignee]

        person
            ? this.triggerTransition(transitions.ClickCheckTag, {person, status}) : this.triggerTransition(transitions.Free)
    })
```

How to return status from catch in case of error ?

Answer (score 0):

In your try statement you need to check if status equals 404 and then throw an error. Then your catch statement will execute.

```
        try {
            response = await DeviceApi.checkTagAssignment(tagId, token);
            assignee = response.result.assignee
            status = response.result.status; 
            if (status === httpStatusCode.notFound){
             var error404 = { 
               message: "not found", 
               status: httpStatusCode.notFound 
             };
             throw error404 ;
           } else {
             return response.result;
           }
        }
```

[Throw statement documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)